# Making the map on GTA V PC look like PS4 or Xbox One?

Tags: steam, grand-theft-auto-v

Grand Theft Auto 5 for PC is great, but the only complaint I have is the map and general HUD. It seems to have stuck to the edge of my screen, and imagine this happens to anyone else on 1080p. Is there any way to make it like the other next generation consoles and make it have a small gap between the edge of screen and the HUD? I am willing to mod the game if needed.

Comment: If you're playing on a TV and the map is getting cut off then you should be able to fix that by changing the settings for your video card and TV.

Comment: No nothing was been cut off but I just don't like it stuck to the edge because I am used to Xbox and PlayStation versions. Chippies answer was the correct solution for me.

Comment: Ok, the reason why the default behaviour is different than on the consoles is because TVs will normally cut off the edges of whatever they're displaying.

Comment: Well of course when they make games for consoles you know what exact hardware you are dealing with, where as with PC games the user has to do a lot more to make it look good.

Comment: I think you missed my point. The reason why the console versions of GTA V don't put the map and HUD elements on the edge of the screen isn't because it looks better, but because of the unpredictable behaviour of TVs. Most TVs cut off a certain amount of the image at the edges, meaning anything displayed at the edge of the image probably won't be visible on most TVs. On the PC, computer monitors never cut off the edges. So in this case the developers have deal with unpredictable hardware (TVs) on the consoles that doesn't exist on the PC. The PC version looks the way the developers intended.

Comment: So do most people prefer the map stuck to the edge? My consoles never needed any TV optimisation so I am used to the map having a little gap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by going to `Settings -> Display` and adjust Safezone value to fit your needs.